# How to install this Jekyll theme correctly in order to make custom adjustments?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Jekyll, and have encountered a big problem. I'm probably doing something wrong or missing something, but what?

I find it very confusing trying to install the "Agency Jekyll Theme" which is the first theme I'm trying out. Mostly because there are several ways to do it, the commands don't add up and there is a lot of "you can do this" embedded into what you actually have to do to install it.

These are the guides I've been following:

- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/
- https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jekyll-agency/1.2.0
- http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/agency/

Basically, I've tried all the 3 possible ways to install it without success.

I'm running on Windows.

My problem:

`jekyll serve` (ran in my site folder) creates a *_site* folder and content in the subfolders *css*, *img* and *js*. Nothing else is created, not index.html, and other files needed directly under *_site* folder.
In my site root folder, there are only _config.yml and Gemfile, after completing the initial steps.

There seems to be a problem with actually downloading the full theme into my root folder. When I manually download the *agency-jekyll-theme-starter-master.zip* and extract the entire content in my root site folder, there is index.html, _data folder, etc. However, in the assets folder, there is only an *img* folder.

As a result, when I open http://localhost:4000/agency-jekyll-theme-starter/ in a browser there is only a directory listing with the folder "*assets*".

Where do the css folder and its content come from that generates under *_site*?

My workaround:

I run `jekyll build` so that the site in its entirety is placed under *_site* folder. However, with this process, the whole point of using Jekyll is lost because I have to edit the generated HTML files, CSS files, etc. To change simple stuff like renaming the page/navigation "Services" to another word I have to go through the HTML file and replace all occurrences

Answer (score 0):

**My successful attempt to reproduce your issue:**

I tried this method from http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/agency/

> 2. Using the Starter Template
>
> This is the fastest and easiest way to get up and running on GitHub Pages. Simply generate your own repository by clicking [here](https://github.com/raviriley/agency-jekyll-theme-starter/generate), then replace the sample content with your own and configure for your needs.

The [starter template](https://github.com/raviriley/agency-jekyll-theme-starter) (that is also linked on the page above) allowed me to start a code space and commit the repo content into my new branch.

I could reproduce your problem, there were no styles when running `jekyll serve`.

**The reason for the issue:**

The problem is the baseurl in the _config.yml file. It points to a relative path that does not exist in your repository. Your baseurl / path is "", because you run your server from the root folder, most probably both locally and later remotely using GitHub pages.

**The solution for the issue:**

In the _config.yml file in your repo, change this one line

from

> baseurl: "/agency-jekyll-theme-starter" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog

to

> baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog

Check out https://github.com/cadamini/jekyll-agency-test if you like.

I hope this was understandable and helpful and that you can solve your issue with these instructions. Don't hesitate to comment for further clarification.